# Can .tflite capture tf.hub.text_embedding_column() processes?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-lite

Just a general question here, no reproducible example but thought this might be the right place anyway since its very software specific.

I am building a model which I want to convert to `.tflite`. It relies on `tf.hub.text_embedding_collumn()` for feature generation. When I convert to `.tflite` will this be captured such that the resulting model will take raw text as input rather than a sparse vector representation?

Would be good to know just generally before I invest too much time in this approach. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I don't imagine this would work, as we do not support enough string ops to implement that. One approach would be to do this handling through a custom op, but implementing this custom op would require domain knowledge and mitigate the ease-of-use advance of using tf hub in the first place.

There is some interest in defining a set of hub operators that are verified to work well with tflite, but this is not yet ready.